# How to get the tolerance of a dimension in a dxf file with exdxf?

Tags: python, dxf, ezdxf

I am trying to automatically get information from 2D dxf file. The dimension class has no property about tolerance like dxf.dimtm. Such property I can find is in the DXF type Dimstyle, but that is not what I want. I found such information in dxf file looks like

A01 %%C6.14{\H0.2;\S+0.0030^ -0.0000;}

0.0030 is the upper bound and -0.0000 is the lower bound.
How to get that two float using ezdxf?

appreciate to any help

Alex

Answer (score 2):

In general the tolerance values are stored in the DIMSTYLE entity, but can be overridden for each DIMENSION entity, you can get them by the `DimstyleOverride()` class as shown in the following example:

```py
import ezdxf
from ezdxf.entities import DimStyleOverride

doc = ezdxf.readfile('your.dxf')
msp = doc.modelspace()

for dimension in msp.query('DIMENSION'):
    dimstyle_override = DimStyleOverride(dimension)
    dimtol = dimstyle_override['dimtol']
    if dimtol:
        print(f'{str(dimension)} has tolerance values:')
        dimtp = dimstyle_override['dimtp']
        dimtm = dimstyle_override['dimtm']
        print(f'Upper tolerance: {dimtp}')
        print(f'Lower tolerance: {dimtm}')
```

This is a very advanced DXF topic with very little documentation from the DXF creator, so you are on your own to find out the meaning of all the `dim...` attributes. [Here](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/tables/dimstyle_table_entry.html) you can see the result of my research, but no guarantee for the correctness of the information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The logic is that every "dimension" follows the origin dimstyle setting. If I use CAD to change the tolerance information, then the change will be saved as override. So, if i want to get the tolerance of the dimension, i need to get it from the override. Am i correct? sorry for my poor english

Comment: Yes this is correct, and if there are no overridden attributes in the DIMENSION entity the value of the DIMSTYLE entry will be returned.